# Include additional content in append code jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Simple question (I think)

This...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".jg").each(function() {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop()
        }));
    });
});
```

...displays the name of an image file contained in all divs with the class .jg. It wraps the name in h6 tags and appends itself to the .jg div its associated with.

*^^^ No problems there ^^^*

**My question.**

How do I add additional text to the H6?

I want this...

```
text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop()
```

plus this...

```
("Tada!");
```

I could append it to .jg in addition to the H6 like...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".jg").each(function() {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop()
        }));
        $(this).append("Tada!");
    });
});
```

But I simply want it included in the H6 and don't know the syntax to do it?

Eg...

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".jg").each(function () {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop()
            **PLUS SOMETHING ELSE HERE**
        }));
    });
});
```

I'm sure it's basic jQuery syntax, unfortunately whatever I try breaks it :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat the text to the `text` of the `.jg` in the `each` loop.

```
text: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop() + 'Tada!'
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".jg").each(function() {
        $(this).append($('<h6/>', {
            html: $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop() + '<span>Tada!</span>'
        }));
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9nxaLbda/2/)

Comment: Just one more question. How would I append the additional text between span tags? ( "<span>Test</span>" )

Comment: @Bevels If your problem is solved, you can accept answer

Comment: Hmm I did try that and then with brackets.. for some reason I can't get it to display without the inclusion of the <span> tags? https://jsfiddle.net/9nxaLbda/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".jg").each(function() {
        $(this).append('<h6>' + $(this).find('a').attr('href').split('/').pop() + 'Tada!</h6>');
    });
});
```